# how to send a message to facebook messenger using url scheme?

Tags: android, iphone, facebook

Is it possible to send a message to the facebook messenger using url scheme? after searching for schemes I found that messenger opens using fb://messaging/ does anybody know how to attach a message?(without attaching specific userId)

ex: 
twitter://post?message=hello

Answer (score 2):

you should try this

```
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Your message");
    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
    sendIntent.setPackage("com.facebook.orca");

    try {
        startActivity(sendIntent);
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        ToastHelper.show(this, "Please Install Facebook Messenger");
    }
```

It will open Facebook Messenger app, select a friend and the message will be send.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `fb-messenger://share?link=` or `fb-messenger://share?text=`

Comment: For me the `link` worked fine, but for `text` it opens Messenger without fill the message! btw thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don´t think it´s possible - and after all the message always must be 100% user generated so it does not really make sense to attach any message.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I think I have to use facebook sdk to send message to the messenger.

Comment: you can´t send a message to the messenger, as i said... you can only open the messenger: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share#message-dialog

Comment: what message would you send anyway? as i said, it must be 100% user generated.

Comment: I've seen an iOS app sending url to the messenger and then select the user who want to share the url.if it's impossible to do that with the url scheme,may be they use the facebook sdk

Comment: You can use the Message dialog that exists in the SDK to share a url. You will not be able to write the message