# How to share only text on facebook messenger for iOS using url scheme

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, facebook, url-scheme

I want to share only text from my ios app to Facebook messenger.

Is it possible to send a message to the facebook messenger using url scheme?

> ex: fb-messenger://post?text=hello 
>   ex: fb-messenger://send?text=hello 
>   ex: fb-messenger://messaging?text=hello

Objective-C code like

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"fb-messenger://"]]) {
    NSString *msgString = @"Hello World";
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"fb-messenger://send?text=%@", msgString];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Failed to open fb-messenger App ");
}
```

After searching for schemes I found that android is be solved.
Here's [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28455237/how-to-send-a-message-to-facebook-messenger-using-url-scheme)

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Your message");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
sendIntent.setPackage("com.facebook.orca");

try {
    startActivity(sendIntent);
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    ToastHelper.show(this, "Please Install Facebook Messenger");
}
```

I searched all around google and stackoverflow but i didn't find any useful information.

Comment: You can't. According to Facebook Platform Policy the user needs to write the text themself

Comment: Got it, Thanks a lot.

Comment: @DanielWeng did you got the answer.

Comment: can't we even share link to FB Messenger recipients?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on **iOS** as of **Feb 2018**:
`fb-messenger://share?link=encodedLink`

Please note that you can only send a link, you can't compose a message.

Comment: for sharing on Facebook (and messenger) it is now required to use the Facebook SDK, see