# How to send a message to messenger using url scheme?

Tags: flutter, url, dart, facebook-messenger

my problem is I need to pass a message or text in messenger to share in their friends.

for example
this link `https://line.me/R/msg/text/?hi%20there`
will open the line app and you can select which of your friend send the message "hi there"

is there a similar way in messenger or if you guys know other methods that pass a message to messenger can you show it to me.

I visited this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28455237/how-to-send-a-message-to-facebook-messenger-using-url-scheme) and they say that using facebook_sdk will solve this but when I check the facebook_sdk compilation I don't see any similar solution to my problem

I'm using flutter with url_launcher

thank you